# How to model Address relationship with Customer and business ?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to setup a MySQL database where I have customer and business both of whom have address. How can I have an address table separately which could be linked to both Customer and Business tables via Foreign key relationship?

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the party model. A party is an abstract organization or individual. Use Table Inheritance to model this.
2. Use a junction table between MailingAddress and Party.

Using Single Table Inheritance:

```
create table party (
  party_id int primary key,
  type varchar(20) not null, --this should be a char(1) or smallint pointing to a lookup table
  name varchar(255) not null
);

insert into party values 
(1, 'Organization', 'Acme, Inc'),
(2, 'Individual', 'John Doe');

create table mailing_address (
  address_id int primary key,
  address varchar(255) not null --add other address fields
);

insert into mailing_address values
(1, '123 Wall Street...'),
(2, '456 Main Street...');

create table party_mailing_address (
  party_id int,
  mailing_address_id int,

  primary key (party_id, mailing_address_id),

  foreign key (party_id) references party(party_id),
  foreign key (mailing_address_id) references mailing_address(address_id)
);

--assign addresses to the parties:
insert into party_mailing_address values
(1,1),
(2,2);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is something I was looking forward to, i.e. a way to implement it using inheritance. I will try it out this evening.

Comment: Is it better to model it this way or have the address fields in both Customer and Business ? Thoughts ?

Comment: A person or company may have zero, one, or many addresses, and different people may share the same address, so this is the best way to do it, data structure wise. You can add an "address_role" field to the junction table if you want to track say "home" or "work" addresses.

Comment: But it would mean that I would need atleast one join if I need to retrieve either a Business or a Customer. How does that impact performance in a longer run ? I really like this design though, just evaluating the pros and cons.

Comment: Yes, you will need joins. Databases are optimized to do joins very quickly, especially on integers. You want to avoid premature optimization. Try it the correct way first, test performance (using say JMeter), and only if it's the slowest part of your system, consider de-normalization.